# Is there a pie chart slice hover event in Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I just started using Highcharts and I need to capture an event when the user hovers over a slice of the pie and also to get contextual information about that slice. Is there an event for that? I haven't been able to find one in the documentation.

Comment: Is [this](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data.events.mouseOver) what you're looking for?

Comment: Yeah, that's it. Can't believe I didn't see that before. If you add your answer below, I'll mark it as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plotOptions.series` allows [`events.mouseOver`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data.events.mouseOver) and [`events.mouseOut`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data.events.mouseOut) handlers to be added, a la:

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    ...
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            point: {
                events: {
                    mouseOver: function () {
                        $reporting.html('x: ' + this.x + ', y: ' + this.y);
                    }
                }
            },
            events: {
                mouseOut: function () {
                    $reporting.empty();
                }
            }
        }
    },
    ...
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-point-events-mouseover/)